# Want to extract every row regardless of pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm using React-Table to load the data in the page. Now i want to export all the rows in a pdf file regardless of pagination.

I used KendoReact but it was able to extract a single page only.

Comment: Why not building the pdf on the server side ?